# What does "+date+" mean in this context?

Tags: sql-server, java

```
select LTRIM(RTRIM(convert(char(10), max(date), 101))) as str 
from   inventory 
where  date < '" + date + "'"
```

I happen to see this a lot in my Java code. Can someone please re-phrase the query above in plain English? Thank you.

Comment: A java variable to pass value to the sql query. Easy access for sql injection!

Comment: @JSapkota Ah! how could this have been better implemented so as to defend against SQL injection?

Comment: Using [prepared statement](https://www.google.com/search?&q=prepared+statement+in+Java)?

Comment: There is a missing `"` at the start, before the `select`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(char(10), MAX(date), 101))) as str 
FROM   inventory 
WHERE  date < '" + date + "'"
```

> Table: **inventory**
>
> Field: **date** (Your inventory table has a field named `date`)

[MAX(date)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql): Returns the highest date according WHERE conditions.

[CONVERT(char(10), MAX(date), 101)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql): Convert one data type into another applying some style. On this case 101 means U.S. format: `mm/dd/yyyy`. This is a MS SQL-Server specific syntax.

[RTRIM()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rtrim-transact-sql): Returns a character string after truncating all trailing spaces.

[LTRIM()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ltrim-transact-sql): Returns a character expression after it removes leading blanks.

> ```
> Give me the highest date of inventory table, using mm/dd/yyyy format,
> without leading and trailing spaces and considering only records
> where this date is lower than an specific value.
> ```

Comment: I should add: while using Microsoft SQL Server, because [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) won't work with all SQL databases.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, + means concatenation of strings, twice applied to sets of string inputs. + is an overloaded operator in java, which could also mean addition if applied on numeric type inputs.